# How to return dictionary dynamically from frozen dataclass?

Tags: python, dictionary, python-dataclasses

I have a container class that holds various instance type of container as a dictionary in a frozen dataclass. Like so:

```
@dataclass(frozen=True)
class SomeContainer:
    foo: ContainerType1
    bar: ContainerType2
    foobar: ContainerType3
```

Another method that basically accepts `container_types` (list of *foo,bar,foobar*) as input & returns `SomeContainer` like so:

```
def load(container_types) -> SomeContainer:
    return SomeContainer(
        foo=ContainerType1(do_something1()),
        bar=ContainerType2(do_something2()),
        foobar=ContainerType3(do_something3())
    )
```

Now, I would like to have a functionality that can make dataclass key-value pair be optional such that I can dynamically return from `load()` method a new container type.

This is what I intend to have:

```
def load(key:foobarfoobar) -> SomeContainer:
    return SomeContainer(
        key=ContainerTypeN(do_somethingN()),
    )
```

How should I declare the `SomeContainer` class that accept dictionary as optional then?

Comment: You can construct dictionaries by calling the class and passing it keyword arguments. i.e. `return dict(foo=ContainerType1(do_something1()), bar=ContainerType2(do_something2()), foobar=ContainerType3(do_something3())`. Does that help?

Comment: thank you for the answer, but I intend to have something like declaring keyword arguments in my `SomeContainer` class. Something like this:
`@dataclass(frozen=True)
class SomeContainer:
    **kwargs`

I want to dynamically provide key-value pair in my load method

Comment: Sorry, I guess I don't really understand your question. Would it be possible to edit it and provide a [mre] that illustrates what you would like to work (and why it doesn't).